# how to change wordpress site from http to Https ? I am using the7 theme v3

Tags: wordpress, https, wordpress-theming

My website change from http to https.
I am using The7 theme v3.
default contact form of theme and WordPress HTTPS plugin not work.
it return error in console
"wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)".

and also page not load properly.css and js path url is use http not https.
how to solve?please help.

and some times admin side is not open.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured your SSL correctly, you should move your website from public_html to private_html. Your ssl should work then.

As for the http to https urls you can install a plug-in which converts all http links to https.

If you don't have a private_html ask your hosting provider for an alternative.  They might renamed it.

Comment: I have already applied in other website.But did not require change folder name from public_html to private_html.

Comment: No, not rename. Your root contains 2 folders, one public and one private. That's how my host works with SSL certificates. Never rename or edit root folders.

Comment: i can not find private_html. see screen short

Comment: admin side properly work using HTTPS.but front side not load properly